# bijective Lipschitz function and the image of a rectifiable set

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $g: A\rightarrow B$ be a bijective function which is locally lipschitz, where $g^{-1}$ is continuous and $A,B\subset R^{n}$ open subsets. Prove that if $D\subset A$ rectifiable, then $g(D)$ is rectifiable.

I am thinking about this problem, and don't really see why will we be needing for the inverse to be a continuous function as well. I am not very sure on my reasoning when claiming $g(\partial D)=\partial g(D)$.

I know that $\partial D$ has measure $0$ (since $D$ is rectifiable) and $g$ maps sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$, but other than that, I don't really know what else may I need to use.

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Could you check the first line? You write 'Let $g : A \to B$ be a bijective rectifiable set...' which doesn't seem sensible. Should it be 'Let $g: A\to B$ be a bijective Lipschitz function...' in line with the title to your question?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but $D \subset R^n$ (or any other metric space) is $(n)$-rectifiable exactly when there is some Lipschitz map $f: K \to D$ from a bounded set $K \subset R^n$ onto $D$. Thus we have $g(D) = g(f(K)).$ Clearly the composition of Lipschitz functions is itself Lipschitz, and since both $f$ and $g$ are onto their composition definitely is. Thus $g(D)$ must be $(n)$-rectifiable as well. I don't see where the other conditions need to be used, but I could very well be missing something (been a long time since I touched this material)